# angular2-json-schema-form change add button text of type="array"

Tags: angular, angular-schema-form

I'm using https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form/ in my angular 4 project which refers to the http://schemaform.io/ for angular js. I have a JSON scheme which contains several objects of type="array". The lib adds a button to add more objects to the array. The default title is "Add to {object name}".

My question is how can I change the title of the button because the description should be in German. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the [default Array Widget](https://github.com/makinacorpus/ngx-schema-form/blob/master/projects/schema-form/src/lib/defaultwidgets/array/array.widget.ts) as described [here](https://github.com/makinacorpus/ngx-schema-form#creating-a-custom-widget).

You will need to copy the original template and replace the English button descriptions with German ones:

```
<button (click)="removeItem(i)" class="btn btn-default array-remove-button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ---> Remove <---
</button>
</div>
<button (click)="addItem()" class="btn btn-default array-add-button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ---> Add <---
</button>
```